# logrotate problems after resetting mysql root password

Tags: mariadb, logrotate, ubuntu-18.04, password-recovery

A while ago, I had to reset my forgotton root password for mysql (strictly speaking mariadb) along a suitable how-to (might have been this
https://devanswers.co/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-ubuntu/ ) and used a strong password. While everything seemed to work fine afterwards, one issue keeps popping up: the daily cron job for logrotate fails:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

As the logrotate config contains the helpful line

```
# If this fails, check debian.conf!
```

[sic], I took a look at `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`:

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

Clearly, the newly created password should have been added to this file (twice, or I'll have problems with the next software update), but wasn't. While I might just do so now, this would conflict with the first line `DO NOT TOUCH!`
I suppose this file would be rewritten by the system at some point? If so, what is the correct other place to store the new password that I created "manually"?

Comment: Is there any file "/root/.my.cnf" on the server containing old password?

Comment: @Kunal No result from `sudo find / -name .my.cnf`